# After the integration with GCLB, will it be possible to route multiple api configs in a single gcp api gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-api-gateway

GCP API-Gateway documentation says the following

> A gateway only host a single API config. You cannot deploy multiple API configs to the same gateway.
> https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/glossary

But I want to manage a **separate swagger file for each api.**

I learned that the api-gateway roadmap includes **integration with the GCLB.**

Does this mean that I can expect to be able to configure the following?

```yml
paths:
  /users:  -> users.config.yml
  /orders: -> orders.config.yml
```

Comment: Not yep, but it's also in the roadmap.

Comment: I searched in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) of GCP but didn't find anything. You can research there and in case you did not find anything, open a Feature Request with the proper components. In this way, you can track the advance of that request.

Comment: thank you. I opened feature request with [Public Trackers > Cloud Platform > Networking > API Gateway] components.https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169904955